# How do you re-create the brightness and higher harmonics on top of a sine in this bass? (Shadow Child - 23 or AC Slater Final Fantasy)

Tags: ableton-live, bass

On the bass patches for both Shadow Child - 23 (around 1:30) and AC Slater - Final Fantasy Original Mix(from the beginning) they have a clean bright harmonic I'm having trouble recreating. How do they get that clean bright upper end of this bass?

I've tried in Massive with a sine wave, and some delay/chorus. It sounds like maybe a sine wave with some sort of delay or fattener... I did try some ring mod, and warping the sine wave a bit, but the highs are still not as bright and are a bit muddy. How else can I approach getting the higher frequency harmonics and keep it sounding so clean. It doesn't sound like there is too much to it, maybe a clever processing chain?

This link is my current best attempt in Massive. I'm also open to trying it in Serum, any of the Ableton Suite synths or Reason ones.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=19VBJaOgmo4UKg_pL_XHJ_l84uwoai9OY

I have Ableton Live Suite 10.1, Serum, Massive and Reason 7. Any If you can me fill in the blanks, to my idea or if I've started in the wrong direction on this patch, that would be awesome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98440/discussion-between-cmims-and-mark).

Comment: Suggestion - analyse this by pitch changing the entire section of the track up two octaves. It's much easier to analyse what the bass is doing once it's up in a usable range.

Comment: That's a really helpful tip, thanks Mark. I'm going to try this out after work today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I'm doing this in MassiveX.

Two sine-wave oscillators running. The second tracks the first using a relative pitch ratio of 4.76 i.e. the first harmonic frequency is 4.76 multiplied by the frequency of the first oscillator. I can't hear any more harmonics other than the fundamental and the first.

I analysed this by pitch-changing the original track up by two octaves and then reading the fundamental and first harmonic values.

Sounds fairly close to the original.

Comment: Hey Mark, it took me a while with a computer outage, but this did get me pretty close and I can fine tune from here. I've gone with a bit of bending on the wave tables to over emphasize the harmonics and the some low pass to even it out a bit and it sounds good. Thanks!

Comment: Good work mate - glad it helped.